# How can I access the value that is being assigned in a if-else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, random

I am currently working on a website for myself and I have some randomly generated colors which reverse back to the "original".

Now my problem is that I want to access the values which were assigned in an if-else statement.
I know these are private now but is there any way I can still get their value?

The variable gets created outside of the if-else statement.

```
var randomLinks;
```

But the values are put in inside of the if-else statement.

```
if ($("header").hasClass("sticky")){
        $(".navlink").addClass("temp");
        $(".temp").removeClass("navlink");
        $(".temp").addClass("navlinksticky");
        $(".navlinksticky").removeClass("temp");
        randomLinks = $('.navlinksticky');
    } else {
        $(".navlinksticky").addClass("temp");
        $(".temp").removeClass("navlinksticky");
        $(".temp").addClass("navlink");
        $(".navlink").removeClass("temp");
        randomLinks = $('.navlink');
    }
```

I am not very good in jQuery and js, so my code is probably trash. Any corrections are greatly appreciated.

Here is the Project itself:

```js
// JavaScript Document
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var header = document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
})

var checkInterval = 300;
var randomLinks;
window.setInterval(function() {
  if ($("header").hasClass("sticky")) {
    $(".navlink").addClass("temp");
    $(".temp").removeClass("navlink");
    $(".temp").addClass("navlinksticky");
    $(".navlinksticky").removeClass("temp");
    randomLinks = $('.navlinksticky');
  } else {
    $(".navlinksticky").addClass("temp");
    $(".temp").removeClass("navlinksticky");
    $(".temp").addClass("navlink");
    $(".navlink").removeClass("temp");
    randomLinks = $('.navlink');
  }
}, checkInterval);
var original = randomLinks.css('color');
var colors = ['#ee6161', '#00f2a6', '#01c0fa'];

randomLinks.hover(
  function() { //mouseover
    var col2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var newcolor = colors[col2];
    $(this).css('color', newcolor);
  },
  function() { //mouseout
    //$(this).css('color', original);
  }
);
```

```css
.navh1 {
  font-family: utopian, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

.fo1 {
  font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
}

.hs {
  font-family: dystopian, sans-serif;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    /*transition: translateX(-100%) 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);*/
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    /*transition: translateX(0) 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);*/
  }
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
  padding: 40px 30px;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

header>h1>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

header>h1>a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: rgb(255, 126, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

header ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: rgb(255, 126, 0);
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

.navlink {
  color: #000;
}

.navlinksticky {
  color: #fff;
}

.rdmcolorlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

.rdmcolorlink:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: rgb(255, 126, 0);
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

header.sticky {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

header.sticky>h1>a {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
}

header.sticky ul li a {
  color: white;
}

header>h1>a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: rgb(255, 126, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

header.sticky ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: rgb(255, 126, 0);
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.525, 0.195, 0.000, 0.975);
}

button {
  display: none;
  color: #696969;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.png">
  <title>Martin Schmidt</title>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jura:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Bungee+Shade&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/exo8ivx.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/yil2knz.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Preloader -->
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="loader_inner"></div>
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo navh1"><a href="index.html" class="navlink">Martin Schmidt</a></h1>
    <ul>
      <button id="navbtn"> ☰ </button>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="navlink">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ich.html" class="navlink">Über&nbsp;mich</a></li>
      <li><a href="skills.html" class="navlink">Fähigkeiten</a></li>
      <li><a href="lehre.html" class="navlink">Lehre</a></li>
      <li><a href="kontakt.html" class="navlink">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <section class="banner">
    <div class="container fo1">
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-7 col-lg-9">
          <h1 class="hs">Hallo! Ich bin Martin.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 offset-md-0 col-md-5 col-lg-3 offset-lg-0 offset-xl-0 col-xl-3">
          <p class="text-right"><a href="seiten.html" class="rdmcolorlink right">Meine anderen Webseiten</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
          <div class="media">
            <img class="mr-3" src="images/pcet.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h5 class="mt-0">&Uuml;ber mich&nbsp;</h5>
              Hey! Ich bin Martin Schmidt. Ich bin ein lernender Informatik Fachrichtung Systemtechnik bei der PCETERA Informatik. Ich spiele gerne Spiele, mache gerne Websites und am wichtigsten: Ich experimentiere viel mit Computer.&nbsp;&nbsp; </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="row justify-content-md-around m-1">
            <address>
                  <strong>Martin Schmidt&nbsp;</strong><br>
                  PCETERA Informatik<br>
                  <abbr>Winterhaldenstrasse 12&nbsp;</abbr><br>
                  <abbr>3627 Heimberg</abbr><br>
                  <a href="mailto:info@pcetera.ch" class="left">info@pcetera.ch</a>
                </address>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <h2>Meine Fähigkeiten</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 85%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;"> HTML</div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;"> CSS</div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 70%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;"> JAVASCRIPT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft; color: #000;"> AFTER EFFECTS</div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="55" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 55%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft; color: #000;"> PHOTOSHOP</div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;"> PHP</div>
          </div>
          <div class="progress mt-4">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%; animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;"> DREAMWEAVER</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 p-0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/300X200.gif" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 p-0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/300X200.gif" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 p-0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/300X200.gif" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 p-0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/300X200.gif" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 p-0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/300X200.gif" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 p-0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/300X200.gif" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <h2>Kontakt</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-8  col-12 jumbotron">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                <span id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted" style="display: none;">Bitte gib eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein</span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Nachricht</label>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Nachricht" aria-describedby="messageHelp"></textarea>
                <span id="messageHelp" class="form-text text-muted" style="display: none;">Bitte gebe eine Nachricht ein.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <footer class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <p>Copyright © Martin Schmidt. All rights reserved.</p>
              Favicon erstellt von <a href="http://www.freepik.com/" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> auf
              <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/de/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Greetings

Martin

Comment: The issue is that setInterval is a quasi-asynchronous operation.  Your following logic will execute before the 300 milliseconds have passed to assign it a value (for the first time).

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought too, but then how do I make it so it will execute after the 300 milliseconds have passed to assign it a value? Also, when I access the values vie the console it works, no clue why